# How to move elements?

Tags: c#, .net, queue

Say you have an instance of a Queue in .NET (Systems.Generic.Collections.Queue). The queue has 10 elements where element 9 (counting from 0) is the most recently added element in the queue.

So the queue could look like this:

```
{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0}
```

where 0.1 is the next element to be popped out on Dequeue and 1.0 is the most recently added item.

I would like to drop the 5 most recently added items so that
the queue ends up looking like this (I need to maintain the same number of elements in the queue so the size doesn't decrease):

```
{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}
```

What is the fastest way of accomplishing that in .NET

Clarification:

t = 0: Queue is initialized

```
{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
```

t = 1: One element is added

```
{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1}
```

t = 2: One element is added

```
{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2}
```

t = 3: One element is added

```
{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
```

t = 4: Two of the most recently added elements are "dropped" (rewind in time)

```
{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1}
```

Background Info:

I'm pushing samples to a buffer. The buffer is basically a sliding window over a long stream of samples. Sometimes I want to "rewind" the window; that is: move it back in time because the samples I pushed should be discarded. I don't know whether or not the samples should be discarded ahead of time. I have to push the samples, do some calculations on the samples in the "window" and then decide if the window should be "backed up" in time.

UPDATE

Requirements:

1. Implement a buffer X which has a fixed size of N elements. The oldest element in the buffer is at index 0 (X[0]). The newest element in the buffer is at index N-1 (X[N-1])
2. Implement a method 'Write' which writes a sample, s, to the buffer. When a sample is written to the buffer the samples in the buffer are shifted so 
   that X[j] = X[j+1] for j = 0 to j = N-2 and X[N-1] = s.
3. At any given time, a method for the following should be available:

   - Finding the maximum sample value in the buffer
   - Finding the minimum sample value in the buffer
   - Finding the average of the sample values in the buffer
   - Reading a sample value at an arbitrary location in the buffer
4. "Rewind": Implement a method which copies K elements starting from index 0 to index K-1 and places them at the end of the buffer. The sample which was originally at index K-1 would therefore be moved to index N-1 and the sample which was originally at index 0 is moved to index (N-1) - (K-1). The samples at index 0 to index K-1 are subsequently set to 0.

I hope the above clarifies what I want. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "C# Queue"? The C# programming language has no concept of a queue. Do you mean a [`System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)?

Comment: Why would dropping the 5 most recently added elements result in 5 new elements being added to the head of the queue?

Comment: @john - yeah that was a mistake on my part

Comment: A LinkedList<> would do what you want. You can shove things in one end and pop them off the other like a simple queue, and you also have the option to access arbitrary elements. What you're trying to do is distinctly not queue (FIFO) behavior.

Comment: @Enigmativity - because I need to have the same number of elements in the queue.

Comment: In that case, you're not looking for a queue.

Comment: glenebob - queues are fifo afaik ? stacks are lifo...I don't know about linked lists.

Comment: @user1884325 - Then you should say that in your question. Also it isn't clear then why you're adding items to the head of the queue.

Comment: @enigmativity - I would like to drop the 5 most recently added items

Comment: What do you mean "drop"? Remove, or modify?

Comment: @user1884325 - Are you thinking that by adding 5 elements to the head of the queue that 5 element will drop out the other end?

Comment: No, I'm showing the desired result of an operation. My question is what is the fastest operation that will give me the desired result.

Comment: "drop" = remove (as if they were never added)...it's like a "rewind in time" function

Comment: How do you start with ten items, drop five, and end up with 10 items, if drop means remove? You really need to clarify the question.

Comment: @user1884325 - You have a wrong impression of a queue. They are not fixed length. They vary based on how many items you enqueue.

Comment: I know - but it's the closest I could find to what I want...so do you have a better idea?

Comment: Great. Thanks for finally telling us a little bit about the problem you need to solve, instead of telling us about the wrong solution to your problem (a queue). Now, do old samples ever become obsolete - so that you will _never_ need to back up to them again? If so, how old is "too old"?

Comment: @user1884325 - This question has been like pulling teeth. At the end of the day it is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your actual solution will have nothing to do with a queue. A linked list would probably be much better.

Comment: Please read the article that @Enigmativity just linked. Then come back and tell us what the actual problem is. Your problem is not how to use a queue. Your problem is what data structure to use given your specific requirements. Then **please tell us your specific requirements**.

Comment: @Enigmativity Should I un-delete my answer now that we agree a linked list is probably what OP wants?  :p (kidding)

Comment: @glenebob - LOL. I am glad you said you were joking. The OP doesn't necessarily want a linked list. He wants a `Buffer` class. I doubt he really needs the performance that a linked list **might** give him. I think the fixed array might be more than sufficient for his needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using regular arrays and copy methods on those arrays to implement the desired functionality

Answer (score 1):

So, given your new requirements I would implement this class:

```
public class Buffer
{
    public Buffer(int N) { }
    public void Write(double value) { }
    public double Maximum { get { return 0.0; } }
    public double Minimum { get { return 0.0; } }
    public double Average { get { return 0.0; } }
    public double this[int n] { get { return 0.0; } }
    public void Rewind(int k) { }
}
```

This code is clearly just the shell - I've left the inner workings for you to code.

I followed the structure of your requirements precisely.

The code currently compiles which should help make it a good starting point.

I would suggest you implement this first using an array as your underlying data structure (i.e. `double[N]`). If you implement this code and it is efficient enough then you're done. If not, then try using `LinkedList<double>` - this will be harder to code, but it should be faster although without running your code against it there is no way for me to tell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need something like a fixed size [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), although your expected behavior for the `Rewind` operation remains somewhat unclear. So if I misunderstood how that is supposed to work, please clarify this further in your question.

```
public class RewindableRingBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly T[] _values;
    private int _head;  // index of oldest value
    private int _count; // number of elements

    public RewindableRingBuffer(int capacity)
    {
        _values = new T[capacity];
        _head = 0;
        _count = 0;
    }

    public int Count { get { return _count; } }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get 
        {
            if ((uint)index >= (uint)_count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index");
            return _values[(_head + index) % _values.Length];
        }
    }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        var tail = (_head + _count) % _values.Length;
        if (_count < _values.Length)
            _count++; // was not yet filled to capacity.
        else
            _head = (_head + 1) % _values.Length; // remove oldest.
        _values[tail] = value;
    }

    public T Min 
    {
        get { return Enumerate().Min(); }
    }

    public T Max
    {
        get { return Enumerate().Max(); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Enumerate()
    {
        // enumerates oldest to newest.
        for (var i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            yield return _values[(_head + i) % _values.Length];
    }

    public void RewindBy(int num)
    {
        // Goes back in history, by removing the 'num'
        // most recent values.
        _count = Math.Max(0, _count - num);
    }
}
```